# How to assign a value to a variable inside a function and still be able to access it globally

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code

```
let chosenRating = 0;
for(button in ratingButtons){
    ratingButtons[button].onclick = (e) => {
        chosenRating = e.target.innerHTML;
        
        ratingButtons.forEach(btn => {
            btn.classList.remove('selected');
        })
        e.target.classList.add('selected');
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the chosenRating variable globally, but it just says it's 0. I tried to just declare it and not assign it, but then it says it is undefined. When I console log inside the function, right after assigning it to e.target.innerHTML, I get the value that I want. But outside of the function, I don't get the same output.

I thought that since I declared the variable globally, even if I don't assign anything to it then and there, I'll be able to access the variable globally. How can I fix this so that the innerHTML of the last button I click is stored as the value to the chosenRating variable?

Comment: You are reassigning it fine. You're likely forgetting that `onclick` is async, so `chosenRating` is only reassigned when the button is clicked. If you try to use `chosenRating`'s value before the button is clicked, it will still be 0, since you haven't run the reassignment by that point yet.

Comment: why not show more functional code, with html and a little more JS? We also have to solve these puzzles ourselves to find a solution for you? [and what is the reward?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The js snippet I posted is all the code that is relevant to the problem I am having. The HTML is five buttons numbered 1 to 5, and I am wanting to select one of the buttons as my rating, click submit, and show what I selected on the next page. The JS I have above is just changing the color of the chosen button and changing it back to the original look when a different button is subsequently selected. I haven't learned asynchronous JavaScript yet, so I will have to look into that! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -3):

Use `var` instead `let`.
let is a scope variable, so it can't changed.

```
var chosenRating = 0;
```

Comment: `let`-bound variables can be reassigned, unless I'm misinterpreting what your answer says.

Comment: The code is within the same scope as the declaration. `var` will not do anything here. In general suggesting `var` instead of `let` is just not good either. There may be an obscure use case for `var` somewhere, but this isn't it.